# Not a valid zip file. Broken zip file structure Error while applying a label to a file

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, sdk, mip-sdk

I try to add a security label to a Excel xlsx file using a MIP SDK, but when calling

```
// Set the label (replace 'labelId' with the actual ID of the label)
  fileHandler.SetLabel(fileEngine.GetLabelById(labelId),new LabelingOptions() { }, new ProtectionSettings());

  // Commit the changes to the file
  fileHandler.CommitAsync(ouputFilePath).Wait();
```

When I call Commit, i got an error Not a valid zip file. Broken zip file structure.

What can be a possible cause to that? how can I fix it? how can i troubleshoot this
When i got to thw log file I found this:

```
Error   2023-12-10 22:57:33.614 oneds_helper.cpp:520    w3wp (63868)    "Failed to find OneDS client for cloud: 3 and dataBoundary: 0"  mipns::OneDSHelper::GetOneDSHandle  67592
Info    2023-12-10 22:57:33.614 api_log_cache.cpp:58    w3wp (63868)    "{{========================================= API CACHED LOGS BEGIN =========================================================}}" mipns::ApiLogCache::LogAllMessages  67592
Info    2023-12-10 22:57:33.614 oneds_helper.cpp:532    w3wp (63868)    "OneDsHelper::WriteTelemetryEvent(file_commit_async)"   mipns::OneDSHelper::WriteTelemetryEvent 67592
Info    2023-12-10 22:57:33.615 diagnostic_utils.cpp:80 w3wp (63868)    "Send Telemetry. Event Name : [file_commit_async]
    App.ApplicationId: [81d25680-50ed-4037-9a64-534fa34bea6d], Pii: [None]
    App.ApplicationName: [DaxSecurityUploader], Pii: [None]
    App.ApplicationVersion: [1.0], Pii: [None]
    App.SessionId: [], Pii: [None]
    Engine.SessionId: [], Pii: [None]
    Engine.TenantId: [15e7854b-5fb3-4c9c-96db-a8a4dde8752c], Pii: [None]
    Event.CorrelationId: [a42bbc00-e8ef-4852-9bfd-3aebc96c6497], Pii: [None]
    Event.CorrelationIdDescription: [FileHandler], Pii: [None]
    Event.Duration: [0.0041324], Pii: [None]
    Event.ErrorType: [FileIOError], Pii: [None]
    Event.Failed.File: [src\file\api_impl\file_handler_impl.cpp], Pii: [None]
    Event.Failed.Func: [mipns::FileHandlerImpl::CommitAsync], Pii: [None]
    Event.Failed.Line: [851], Pii: [None]
    Event.Failed.Message: [Failed API call: file_commit_async Failed with: [FileIOError: 'Not a valid zip file. Broken zip file structure']], Pii: [None]
    Event.ParentCorrelationId: [481e9ba8-b662-49b5-b355-bdb79c5d9023], Pii: [None]
    Event.ParentCorrelationIdDescription: [FileEngine], Pii: [None]
    Event.UniqueId: [f05adb2c-eb23-4473-aa10-e82263d1ebff], Pii: [None]
    EventInfo.Level: [10], Pii: [None]
    EventInfo.PrivTags: [33554432], Pii: [None]
    Input.FileExtension: [.xlsx], Pii: [None]
    Input.FileSize: [26090], Pii: [None]
    Input.Type: [FilePath], Pii: [None]
    MIP.Version: [1.14.108], Pii: [None]
    Output.FileExtension: [.xlsx], Pii: [None]
    Output.Type: [FilePath], Pii: [None]
    Protection.PFileExtensionBehavior: [Default], Pii: [None]
    iKey: [ce9aa5fb5a414ecebb15af10715bd8ff-831d197e-fc97-4df6-b998-c8c13a0fc3ce-6768], Pii: [None]
"   mipns::WriteTelemetryEventToLog 67592
Error   2023-12-10 22:57:33.615 oneds_helper.cpp:520    w3wp (63868)    "Failed to find OneDS client for cloud: 3 and dataBoundary: 0"  mipns::OneDSHelper::GetOneDSHandle  67592
Info    2023-12-10 22:57:33.615 api_log_cache.cpp:78    w3wp (63868)    "{{========================================= API CACHED LOGS END ==========================================================}}"  mipns::ApiLogCache::LogAllMessages  67592
Info    2023-12-10 22:57:33.615 file_handler_impl.cpp:851   w3wp (63868)    "Ended API task: file_commit_async" mipns::FileHandlerImpl::CommitAsync 67592
Warning 2023-12-10 22:57:33.615 common/api_utils.h:232  w3wp (63868)    "Start calling error callback for API: file_commit_async"   mipns::TryExecuteFailureCallback::<lambda_a70a05f0ef22d998f7290cc77ecbe433>::operator ()    24804
Warning 2023-12-10 22:57:33.622 common/api_utils.h:234  w3wp (63868)    "Ended calling error callback for API: file_commit_async"   mipns::TryExecuteFailureCallback::<lambda_a70a05f0ef22d998f7290cc77ecbe433>::operator ()    24804
```

Im trying tu add a label to a file that is beeing uploaded by the user through WCF service, so i could store the file in a repository witha proper label applied so whenewer next user try to download it, it will be protected with MIP policies.